# map-reduce function in CouchDB

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

I have a java program, that reads all words of a PDF file. I saved the words with the pagenumbers in a database (couchDB). Now I want to write a map and a reduce function, which list each word with the pagenumbers where the word occurs, but if words occur more than once on a page, I want just one entry. The result should be a row with word and a second row with a list (String separated with comma) of pagenumbers. Each word with the pagenumber is a separate document in couchDB.
How can I do this with a map-reduce function (filter same entries of pagenumbers)?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4):

Surely there is more than one way of doing it. I'd go for something simple. Lets say your documents look somewhat like this:

```
{ 'type': 'word-index', 'word': 'Great', 'page_number': 45 }
```

This is a result of finding the word 'Great' on page 45. Now your view index is created by a view function:

```
function map(doc) {
    if (doc.type == 'word-index') {
        emit([doc.word, doc.page_number], null);
    }
}
```

For reduce part just use the "_count" builtin.

Now to get the list of all the occurrences of word "Great" in your book, just query your view with startkey=["Great"] and endkey=["Great", {}]. Now the result would look somewhat like:

```
["Great", 45], 4
["Great", 70], 7
```

Which means that world "Great" appeared 4 times on page 45 and 7 times on page 70. You can extract your comma separated list you needed from it. The number of occurrences is a bonus.

--edit--

You also have to use group_level=2 in your query. If you don't the result of the query would simply be a single row with the count off all the documents you have.

Comment: Thanks for you fast answer. I have to test it later, but if I want a list: Great 45, 70, 234. the word great should listed only one time. And the function should do this for all words (documents) in database.

Comment: How can I manage with a reduce function to filter the multiple pagenumbers?

Comment: Well I don't know Java, or the api bindings for couchdb. My point is that when you query a view like this you will be given the list of key-value pairs. Your keys are of the form ["World", page_number]. To get the list you need just take all rows with the keys having the same first element and extract the second. Thanks to reducing it, its unique.

Just one more thing which I have just realized, you also need to use group_level=2 to your query to get this result. If you don't you'd just get a single row in the result.

Comment: @user2447116 <quote>but if I want a list: Great 45, 70, 234. the word great should listed only one time</quote> Views should only be used for the algorithmic part of your service. Use a list if you (really) need to format the data server-side.